# How to rewrite parent prototype function in a child prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm learning prototypes in JS and I have troubles trying to rewrite my parent prototype function in my child prototype.

In the code below, I'm trying to rewrite the function presentation from my class Personn in order to display the new Etudiant property 'etablissement' as well.

```js
function Personne(nom, age, sexe){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.age = age;
    this.sexe = sexe;
}

Personne.prototype.presentation = function() {
    return 'Bonjour, je suis ', this.nom + ', ' + this.sexe + ' de ' + this.age + ' ans.';
}

function Etudiant(nom, age, sexe, etablissement){
    Personne.call(this, [nom, age, sexe]);
    this.etablissement = etablissement;
}

Etudiant.prototype = Object.create(Personne.prototype);
Etudiant.prototype.constructor = Etudiant;

Etudiant.prototype.presentation = function (){
    return Personne.prototype.presentation.call(this) + ' Je travaille au ' + this.etablissement + '.';
};

let patrick = new Etudiant('patrick', 26, 'etoile de mer', 'Club');
console.log(patrick.presentation()); // this displays 'patrick,5651,etoile de mer, undefined de undefined ans. Je travaille au Club.'
```

Comment: `Etudiant.prototype = Object.create(Personne.prototype);
Etudiant.prototype.constructor = Etudiant;` Nice one! **So many** people get that bit wrong, but that's spot-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Personne.call(this, [nom, age, sexe]);
```

With [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), you pass discrete arguments, not an array of arguments. Either change that to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which does take an array (or any array-like):

```
Personne.apply(this, [nom, age, sexe]);
```

or make the arguments discrete:

```
Personne.call(this, nom, age, sexe);
```

Live Example:

```js
function Personne(nom, age, sexe){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.age = age;
    this.sexe = sexe;
}

Personne.prototype.presentation = function() {
    return 'Bonjour, je suis ', this.nom + ', ' + this.sexe + ' de ' + this.age + ' ans.';
}

function Etudiant(nom, age, sexe, etablissement){
    Personne.call(this, nom, age, sexe);
    this.etablissement = etablissement;
}

Etudiant.prototype = Object.create(Personne.prototype);
Etudiant.prototype.constructor = Etudiant;

Etudiant.prototype.presentation = function (){
    return Personne.prototype.presentation.call(this) + ' Je travaille au ' + this.etablissement + '.';
};

let patrick = new Etudiant('patrick', 26, 'etoile de mer', 'Club');
console.log(patrick.presentation()); // this displays 'patrick,5651,etoile de mer, undefined de undefined ans. Je travaille au Club.'
```

---

Side note: If you're going to use constructor functions and the `prototype` property, in modern JavaScript (ES2015+) you can do that more easily with `class` syntax:

```js
class Personne {
    constructor(nom, age, sexe){
        this.nom = nom;
        this.age = age;
        this.sexe = sexe;
    }

    presentation() {
        return 'Bonjour, je suis ', this.nom + ', ' + this.sexe + ' de ' + this.age + ' ans.';
    }
}

class Etudiant extends Personne {
    constructor(nom, age, sexe, etablissement) {
        super(nom, age, sexe);
        this.etablissement = etablissement;
    }

    presentation() {
        return super.presentation() + ' Je travaille au ' + this.etablissement + '.';
    }
}

let patrick = new Etudiant('patrick', 26, 'etoile de mer', 'Club');
console.log(patrick.presentation()); // this displays 'patrick,5651,etoile de mer, undefined de undefined ans. Je travaille au Club.'
```

It creates effectively the same thing (there are some minor differences, the main one being the constructors can't be called as normal functions — which you usually don't want them to be). Importantly, it still uses prototypical inheritance, constructor functions, and the `prototype` property; the syntax just makes it easier to set things up, and more declarative.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and your time, it works perfectly. Yeah I know about the class syntax and I'm familiar with it but I wanted to understand prototypes in order to fully understand js.

Comment: @EmmanuelMadarassou - Sure, makes sense. Just beware that constructor functions and the `prototype` property *use* prototypes, but indirectly. If you want to understand prototypes themselves, you might look at `Object.create` and `Object.setPrototypeOf` (that latter one is best avoided in real code, but can be useful when you're playing around to understand prototypical inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for your advise I'll look into it.